# Getting Distinct records for a day but counting them multiple times for date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a query where i am searching for order numbers. I need to filter the order numbers unique for the day. For that i used count(distinct order_number) in my main query. This query takes start and end date from the front end and uses them. However i have a catch, if there is same order_number for 2 days in the range it will be counted for both of the days. i.e. 
Counting the number of unique orders for a day. Initially i thought to use some loop over dates and sum the results, but that does not looks right to me. I would be more interested to use the same query and modify it for distinct orders based on date. Here is my query :

```
SELECT 'site1' AS site,
  DATE_FORMAT(l.login_time, '%m/%d/%Y') AS DATE,
  COUNT(DISTINCT osh.order_num) AS total_orders
FROM order_history o
INNER JOIN logs l ON o.userID = l.id
WHERE o.date_time BETWEEN 1380524400 AND 1380610799
  AND l.LOGIN BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1380524400) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1380610799)
GROUP BY DATE
```

Example

Suppose for date 29Aug, i have orders o1,o2,o1,o3,o2 i will count them as 3 distinct orders i.e. o1,o2,03
for 30 Aug, i have orders o1, o4, o4, o1 i will count them as 2 distinct orders i.e. o1, o4

but when i query for 29-30 aug i must get count of 3+2 = 5 i.e. o1 is counted twice in the range sicne it belongs to two diff dates.

Comment: Some example data would make this clearer

Comment: I guess I don't understand the underlying data enough to offer a suggestion. In this case, can the same order_num values exist on different dates? I would venture to guess however that this is a case where having actual date fields rather than UNIX timestamp values could make this problem easier

Comment: What relevence does `site` have in the query?

Comment: it is not much relevant. can be ignored for the sake of my question

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case the `WITH ROLLUP` modifier might server your purpose

```
SELECT 'site1' AS site,
  DATE_FORMAT(l.login_time, '%m/%d/%Y') AS `DATE`,
  COUNT(DISTINCT osh.order_num) AS total_orders
FROM order_history o
INNER JOIN logs l ON o.userID = l.id
WHERE o.date_time BETWEEN 1380524400 AND 1380610799
  AND l.LOGIN BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1380524400) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1380610799)
GROUP BY `DATE` WITH ROLLUP
```

This would add an extra row at the end of your data that would sum the `total_orders` data (with a NULL value for `DATE`)

Here is documentation on this modifier: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html